# Call multiple methods in a defined order

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

Picture a case like this:

I have a controller action (or service method) where I need to call three methods in a consecutive order, each method has a single responsibility.

```
public return_type MyMethod(_params_) {
    // .. some code

    Method_1 (...);
    Method_2 (...);
    Method_3 (...);

    // ... some more code
}
```

A developer can make the mistake of calling Method_2 before Method_1, or at least we can say that nothing forces him to follow this order, or to get an exception when the order isn't followed.

Now we can call Method_2 inside Method_1, and Method_3 inside Method_2, but that doesn't seem right when each method handles a completely different responsibility.

Is there a design pattern for this situation? Or any "clean" way to handle this?

Comment: What do these methods do? What would happen if the caller called them in the wrong order?

Comment: You could write tests to ensure the correct order and avoid mistakes. If proper named they will reveal the intent as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what facade pattern do.
Try to extract the three methods to another class, and make them private. Expose  a single method MyMethod that calls the other methods in the desired order. Clients should use Facade.MyMethod

More details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: If his/her fellow developers have access to that code to, they could still mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should leave control of execution for yourself and give possibility just to set what should be executed.

```
public interface IMethodsExecutor
{
    void Execute();
    void ShouldRunMethod1();
    void ShouldRunMethod2();
    void ShouldRunMethod3();
}

public class MethodsExecutor: IMethodsExecutor
{
    private bool _runMethod1;
    private bool _runMethod2;
    private bool _runMethod3;

    public MethodsExecutor()
    {
        _runMethod1 = false;
        _runMethod2 = false;
        _runMethod3 = false;
    }

    public void ShouldRunMethod1()
    {
        _runMethod1 = true;
    }
    public void ShouldRunMethod2()
    {
        _runMethod2 = true;
    }
    public void ShouldRunMethod3()
    {
        _runMethod3 = true;
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
    }
    private void Method2()
    {
    }
    private void Method3()
    {
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        if (_runMethod1)
        {
            Method1();
        }
        if (_runMethod2)
        {
            Method2();
        }
        if (_runMethod3)
        {
            Method3();
        }
    }
}
```

So that the usage will be:

```
IMethodsExecutor methodsExecutor = new MethodsExecutor();
methodsExecutor.ShouldRunMethod1();
methodsExecutor.ShouldRunMethod3();
methodsExecutor.Execute();
```